# Salesforce empApi (pushTopic) error

Tags: lightning-web-components, streaming-api, pushtopic

I have a managed package that is deployed at multiple sites without issue however at one site i am getting a an error thrown to the listener (I am subscribing to a pushTopic from an LWC component like in the example here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation).

The main difference form the example it that the subscribe is taking place in the LWC connectedCallback() and not on button click, however this is the same for every environment the package is deployed to and there are no issues in any others.

{"id":"26","successful":false,"channel":"/meta/handshake","failure":{"reason":"","httpCode":0,"connectionType":"long-polling","transport":{},"message":{"id":"26","version":"1.0","minimumVersion":"1.0","channel":"/meta/handshake","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","callback-polling"],"advice":{"timeout":110000},"ext":{"empJs":true,"channelName":"/topic/mytopicname"}}}}

I have looked at the streaming api error codes and cant find any information for error code 0 (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/streaming_error_codes.htm)

I have verified that push topics are enabled and that the user profile has access to the streaming API and Read permission on the object.

Has anyone seen this kind of failure before / might be able to point me in the right direction, it only seems to be an issue for this one site and the package is working as expected at all others.